# Chrome Extension: Extension is not injecting content script when devtools is opened

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, permissions, google-chrome-devtools

Building a Chrome Extension that adds a devtools panel. That part is working. The dev tools panel needs to be able to grab information from the current page.

The only way I see how to do it, is using a content script. Ideally I don't want to require the "tabs" or "" permissions. I'm fine with them being optional permissions".

My content scripts that I inject only appear to work on the pages that I have specified in my manifest file. I want them to work on any page the user inspects so my panel can display information.

User clicks a button in panel - I request optional permissions for "tabs" and "" in my panel.js

my devtools page .js checks for "tabs" and "" permission.
If permission is granted, I send background.js a message - load this content script.

Recieving the message doesn't seem to matter on Background.js's end as the content script loads automatically regardless on URL's specified in the manifest. It does not however appear on pages you inspect.

CODE
(in order of how it was explained above)

Button in panel.html
`<button id="load">Load Dev Info</button>`
https://github.com/williamspiro/HubSpot-Developer-Extension/blob/c23b8cad6f1787264bb3e8b3673c594a7db5fe7e/panel.html#L8

Permission request in Panel.js

```
document.querySelector('#load').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // Permissions must be requested from inside a user gesture, like a button's
    // click handler.
    chrome.permissions.request({
      permissions: ['tabs'],
      origins:['<all_urls>']
    }, function(granted) {
      // The callback argument will be true if the user granted the permissions.
      if (granted) {
       console.log("Perm granted");


      } else {
        console.log("Perm denied");
      }
    });
  });
```

https://github.com/williamspiro/HubSpot-Developer-Extension/blob/c23b8cad6f1787264bb3e8b3673c594a7db5fe7e/panel.js#L2-L18

permissions check if granted - sendMessage with content script name to background JS and devtools.js(loaded on devtools.html)

```
name: "devtools-page"
});


backgroundPageConnection.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
// Handle responses from the background page, if any
});


console.log("devtools.js ran");








chrome.permissions.contains({
    permissions: ['tabs'],
    origins: ['<all_urls>']
    }, function(result) {
    if (result) {
        // The extension has the permissions.
        // Relay the tab ID to the background page
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            tabId: chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId,
            scriptToInject: "hsInspector.js"
        });
    } else {
        // The extension doesn't have the permissions.


    }
});
```

https://github.com/williamspiro/HubSpot-Developer-Extension/blob/c23b8cad6f1787264bb3e8b3673c594a7db5fe7e/devtools.js#L7-L35

Receive message to background.js - inject content script

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(devToolsConnection) {
    // assign the listener function to a variable so we can remove it later
    var devToolsListener = function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
        // Inject a content script into the identified tab
        console.log("script:",message.scriptToInject);
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(message.tabId,
            { file: message.scriptToInject });
    }
    // add the listener
    devToolsConnection.onMessage.addListener(devToolsListener);

    devToolsConnection.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
         devToolsConnection.onMessage.removeListener(devToolsListener);
    });
});
```

https://github.com/williamspiro/HubSpot-Developer-Extension/blob/c23b8cad6f1787264bb3e8b3673c594a7db5fe7e/background.js#L38-L52

It appears the background JS part does not matter, because in manifest I have the content script mentioned in the manifest causing it to get injected on all URL's that match but not inspected pages.

Permissions and content scripts in manifest.json

```
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "optional_permissions": [
        "https://app.hubspot.com/*",
        "https://app.hubspotqa.com/*",
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "mac-text-cursor.svg",
        "mac-text-cursor.png"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "run_at": "document_idle",
        "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "design-manager.js","hsInspector.js"],
        "css": ["hsDarkIde.css"],
        "document_idle": "document_start",
        "matches": ["https://app.hubspot.com/*", "https://app.hubspotqa.com/*"]
    }],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
```

https://github.com/williamspiro/HubSpot-Developer-Extension/blob/66ee912d56b88be052182a91257af28a4e356558/manifest.json#L25-L46

The content script I am trying to inject from the devtools is hsInspector.js

I only care to have this file get loaded if the devtools injects it. It doesn't need to load on the "matches" pages at all.

EXPECTED AND ACTUAL RESULTS

Expected result is that when inspecting a page, if you go to the extension's dev tools tab, and have the permissions required, the content script will be injected into the page.

[if that were working my goal would be to then make the content script do this]
Content script will be used to grab data from the page, message background.js the required data, background.js messages panel.js the data, panel js would render what it needs to in the panel.

Actual result: content script is not loading into the inspected page, but is instead loading onto the "matches" URLs specified under content_scripts.

If you have questions please ask. I am not an expert at building chrome extensions, so maybe I'm making this way more complicated than it needs to be. Really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) The [documentation says](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow) you can use chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(), 2) runtime.sendMessage is received only in runtime.onMessage which you add in a weird cross-window way via backgroundPageConnection - not sure why you're doing it like that, it's almost always wrong, 3) the idea of chrome.permissions checking is to confirm a specific URL (the current tab's URL in your case), not `<all_urls>`, 4) "content_scripts" declares the auto-injected scripts so AFAICT you don't need it.

Comment: @wOxxOm first - ty for responding.

#1 I wasn't fully sure I understood how to use the eval function and it cautions to use a content script instead of eval for security reasons


regarding #2 I was going this route because I was following https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#solutions

I concur that doing this cross window is convoluted and complicated I just didn't see another way of doing it.

#3 makes sense, will try removing permissions req. and check, very happy about that.

#4 that's what I figured. I'll remove it from here.

Comment: re #2, your code was incomplete so I mistook a port connection for a backgruond window reference, yet the problem is the same: runtime.sendMessage can be received only in runtime.onMessage, not by a port's onMessage so you need to either send to an opened port via yourport.postMessage() or declare a runtime.onMessage listener. OTOH you probably don't need to send any messages since your devtools panel's script should be able to run chrome.tabs.executeScript directly.

Comment: It appears the eval method is working flawlessly. Tried for the sake of experimentation getting chrome.tabs.executeScript to work as well but wasn't getting anything. Wasn't throwing errors, but the file also wasn't being injected.

I think using eval will allow me to do what I need to do with this extension. 
I really appreciate your help here it was very valuable, and all of my extension's users will really appreciate what your help allows me to give them.

Comment: Try debugging your devtools panel: detach devtools to a separate window, focus it, press Ctrl-Shift-i (or the equivalent for your OS) to open a second window with devtools-on-devtools where you can inspect your panel and switch execution context in the console toolbar as well as debug the code.